# Passing arrays to a function call (Buffer Overflow)

Tags: disassembly, buffer-overflow, stack-variables

I need to execute a call to `cat` on a target file using a buffer overflow in a challenge app (can't execute on the stack, but can use `libc`). For reference, in `C` this is valid code for what I'm trying to do:

```
int main(void) {
        char * const argv[] = {"cat", "/etc/target/file"};
        char * const envp[] = {NULL};;
        execve("/bin/cat", argv, envp);
}
```

I can load some null-terminated strings up on the target and I've also determined the address of `execve`. Here's the info I have:

```
"/bin/cat" @ 0xbfffffb9:
"cat" @ 0xbfffffbe
"/etc/target/file" @ 0xbffff96f

execve @ 0x804831c
```

I can overwrite the `EIP` and following bytes with a string like:

```
"AAAA....AAA" + EIP + [RETURN ADDR] + ARG1 + ARG2 ....
```

In the string above I can replace `EIP` with the address of `execve` and jump to the function, but that's where things go sour for me. I've never set up a stack for arrays and couldn't find a google example of using arrays in a classic buffer overflow.

How can I set up the stack with array parameters for my function call? What does my stack need to look like in this case?

Answer (score 2):

What you're actually doing there is passing pointers to the array, not the array itself. If you look at the declarations:

```
    char * const argv[] = {"cat", "/etc/target/file"};
    char * const envp[] = {NULL};
    execve("/bin/cat", argv, envp);
```

'argv' and 'envp' are pointers to the array.

Typically, it's easiest to just ROP to execve('command', NULL, NULL) to avoid fancy setup. Why not execve('/bin/bash', NULL, NULL) then cat the file from the spawned shell?

Otherwise you can finagle some pointers to make it work - pass it pointers to  NULL-pointer terminated arrays of strings that contain your args.